# Finding a filename match in two directories and writing the matched filename to an array

Tags: php

I have looked on Stackover for a simular issue but can't find a solution.

I am trying to write a script that looks at the content of two directories to findout if a filename match can be found in both
directories. If a match is found write the name of the matched filename to an array.

The first thing I am doing is using""scandir" to create an array of data from the first directory.
In the "foreeach"loop through the array from the "scandir" result and perform a "file_exists" using the variable "$image1"
to fing a match in the seconds directory "allimages/boardsclean". If a match is found write the filename to the "$found_images" array.

Testing the result of the "$found_images" array I am not seeing the result I was expecting.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
$c1 = 0;
$c2 = 0;
$scan = scandir('allimages/temp1');

$found_images = array();
foreach ($scan as $image1) {
    if (file_exists('allimages/temp1/'.$image1) && ('allimages/temp2/'.$image1)) {
            echo "file match in Scan $image1</br>";
            $found_images[] = 'allimages/adminclean/'. $image1;
      $c1++;
        } 
}
echo $c1."</br>";

foreach ($found_images as $image3) {
    echo "file match $image3 </br>";
    $c2++;
}
echo $c2."</br>";
```

Comment: `&& ('allimages/temp2/'.$image1)` this looks a bit off.

Comment: @Remy Hi, when you say "this looks a bit off" what do you mean?

Comment: I would assume you want to test if that file exists, it's now only wrapped in parenthesis. Your current conditional will evaluate to `true` if `file_exists('allimages/temp1/'.$image1)` is true now. So I assume you wanted to test: `file_exists('allimages/temp1/'.$image1) && file_exists('allimages/temp2/'.$image1)`

Comment: @Remy Looking at the line "if (file_exists('allimages/temp1/'.$image1) && ('allimages/temp2/'.$image1)) {" it looks correct to me. It's not producing any syntax errors.

Comment: it's syntactically correct but it's a logic error :p. `('allimages/temp2/'.$image1)` this does not test for file existence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need to test for the file from the `scandir` because, well... it's already there and was returned.  Second, you don't test for the one in the second directory.  You need:

```
if(file_exists('allimages/temp2/'.$image1)) {
```

However, just scan both directories and compute the intersection of the returned arrays which will give you files common to both directories.  It's as simple as:

```
$found = array_intersect(scandir('allimages/temp1'), scandir('allimages/temp2'));
```

Then you can filter out directories if you want and add `allimages/adminclean/` in the array or when needed.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your replay. I didn't think to use array_intersect. Works perfectly. After populating the $found array I then used $result = array_unique($found); to remove any duplicate filenames.